# Add layout in whole application (Android)

Tags: android

My every activity in application extend **BaseActivity**, where I want to add dynamically with some information. I'm using something like this:

```
View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.ad_layout, (ViewGroup) getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView());
```

This code adds me layout everywhere, indeed, but It's at the top. I want to add it at bottom. How can I fix it?

This code is **onCreate** method, BaseActivity is **abstract** class, it does not have own Layout.

Comment: inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ad_layout, getMiddleContent());
 try this

Comment: @anonymous What's getMiddleContent() ?

Comment: create LinearLayout at buttom in your BaseActivity xml.
And put this method in BaseActivity 
protected LinearLayout getMiddleContent() {
        return middlelayout;
    }

Comment: where is this code writen ? in base activity ?

Comment: where middlelayout is the LinearLayout which we had taken in our BaseActivity xml

Comment: call it at every activity, at end of the oncreate, best solution create some method in baseactivity and call every activity

Comment: @sush i had clearly said thai put this code in BaseActivity.

Comment: yeah make it as method